# In Android, Where to load SoundPool? In Oncreate or need to create a separate method?

Tags: android, soundpool

I am programming a board game in android and need a sound effect for every click.I am using sound pool. There will be a lot of clicks and so I wanted to know where I have to declare the SoundPool and load it? In the onCreate function , or have a function that creates and loads and plays the sound and is called at every click?

```
//make soundpool public
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//load sound here and play wherever needed
   int soundID=soundPool.load(this,R.raw.metalimpact,1);
}


//or put it all in a function
private void makeSound(){
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
final int soundID=soundPool.load(this,R.raw.metalimpact,1);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){

        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {

            soundPool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1f);
        }});
}
```

What is the right way to impement the SoundPool?

Will there be performance issues in the ways I have implemented it?

When should I release the soundpool object?..In the OnDestroy or onPause()?

Also SoundPool has been deprecated, but my min api level supported is 11. So what should I do?
Please help!!

Comment: Where do you get the information that `SoundPool` has been deprecated? Are you referring to the deprecation the direct SoundPool constructor (instead of using `SoundPool.Builder`)?

Comment: when i write the code SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100); in android studio, it crosses out Soundpool and says deprecated

Comment: That's only the deprecation of this particular usage of `Soundpool`. From API Level 21 and up you are supposed to create SoundPools via the builder object as explained in the API docs. The `SoundPool` class is not deprecated by itself.

Comment: So if I create SoundPools via the builder, then will it work on devices tht have lesser than api level 21 since my min api is set to 11.